# R ggplot Coincidence plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a database of patients with multiple conditions and am trying to create a graphic showing associations between these conditions. More specifically, i'd like to obtain something like below:

[image]

My data is organized as:

```
 mal1 mal2 mal3 etc.
 0    0    1
 1    1    0
 0    1    0 etc.
```

I create the data as I want it to be shown using the following code:

```
X <- as.matrix(hdat2)
out <- crossprod(X)   
diag(out) <- 0
```

And i create the plot with:

```
out<- melt(out)
out$value[which(out$value==0)]<-NA
g <- ggplot(data.frame(out), aes(Var1, Var2)) + geom_point(aes(size = value), colour = "black") + theme_bw() + xlab("") + ylab("")
g + scale_size_continuous(range=c(2,10))+
```

As a result i obtain this plot

[image]

**I'd like to hide the symetric half of the plot**, which i think is misleading (similarly as how, i correlation matrices i can hide the symetric half). However, i'm not sure about how to do it.

Could anyone help ?
Thanks

Comment: Subset your data to only include the half you want.

Comment: Why do you say it is misleading? One way to address it would be to do something similar to the original plot you linked and scale it to present percentages. That would make the dot at (A, B) a different size and meaning than the dot at (B, A) (percentage of A with B vs percentage of B with A, or vice versa).

Comment: Misleading was maybe not the right term. I wanted to say that it was harder for readers to understand the figure with both halves. I'll try to subset the data. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some reproducible data:

```
mat <-
  data.frame(
    malA = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE, c(0.2,0.8))
    , malB = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE, c(0.3,0.7))
    , malC = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE, c(0.4,0.6))
    , malD = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE, c(0.5,0.5))
  )

out <- crossprod(as.matrix(mat))   
diag(out) <- 0
```

Here is an example limiting down to just the half you are interested in using `dplyr`:

```
toPlotHalf <-
  melt(out) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(factor(.))
              , starts_with("Var")) %>%
  filter(as.numeric(Var1) < as.numeric(Var2))

ggplot(toPlotHalf
       , aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value), colour = "black") +
  theme_bw() + xlab("") + ylab("") +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(2,10))
```

[image]

Note, however, that in this way your plot is going to be dominated by particular maladies that are very common. Alternatively, you can present the percentage of people with each malady that have the other malady (note that now the reciprocal points are not (necessarily) the same size:

```
toPlot <-
  prop.table(out, 1) %>%
  melt() %>%
  filter(value > 0)



ggplot(toPlot
       , aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = value), colour = "black") +
  theme_bw() + xlab("") + ylab("") +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(2,10))
```

[image]